# Able to write but unable to read file

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, file-handling

I am using VSC for writing python scripts to read/write file. I am able to write file using the below code:

```
with open("score_card.txt", mode="w+") as file_data:
    file_data.write("23")
```

but when trying to read the file using the below code:

```
with open("score_card.txt", mode="w+") as file_data:
    print(file_data.read())
```

it is not giving anything in the terminal.

Comment: forgot to add a tab in the first code while posting. kindly ignore that.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and fix your code.

Comment: Better only use modes `w` for write, and `r` for read (which is default), so `open("score_card.txt")` will read

Comment: Do you know what the w+ means in your code?

Comment: `w+` : Opens a file for both writing and reading. Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for reading and writing..

Comment: So the second part, erase the file, getting empty thing and empty file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in read mode. Here's an example:

```
with open("score_card.txt", mode="r") as file_data:
    print(file_data.read())
```

You can learn more about the open function modes here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

An important thing to remember is that the `w+` mode is for **truncating** and writing. This means that it will wipe the file contents, so when you try to read it, there is nothing in the file. You should use mode='r' on all files that you don't intend to edit.

Comment: Hi Joe, Yes I tried that as well still same issue, I am able to write anything in file but not able to read it.

Comment: If you previously opened it in `w+` mode, the file was wiped and is empty now. I'd recommend checking the file and adding some lines to it then trying again with `r` mode.

Comment: Just tried still not working, also there is data in the file before reading I am cross-checking. do you think it might be some VS or permission issue? Although I am not getting any such warning.

Comment: Looks like it was some project directory issue, Create the same project in a new directory and now able to read and write.